# Create powerpoint shape with vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a VBA that creates a green up arrow with no border. Currently the VBA is creating a green arrow with a black border. Can anyone help me out with this? My code is below. I tried  shp.Line.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(137, 143, 75)and was still getting the black outline.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Up_Arrow()     
    Dim i As Integer     
    Dim shp As Shape     
    Dim sld As Slide

    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(35, 10, 10, 5.0399, 8.6399)    
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(137, 143, 75)      
    shp.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(137, 143, 75)              
End Sub
```

Update: Probably not the most sophisticated way to do it but following line of code worked.

shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(137, 143, 75)

Comment: You need to change the border thickness to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse
```

is what you need.

In fact, you can obtain the code required by recording a macro :)

Comment: shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 0, 0)

Comment: Yeah, that would be the macro recorder that Microsoft yanked out of Powerpoint in the 2007 version, leaving us to wade through a Hoover dam worth of unstructured blogs and guesswork to try to determine how to format VBA-created objects using the mind bending new Themes system. (Which is how I stumbled upon this answer.) Your main answer was useful (hence my upvote), but your aside comment sadly has become a case of "If only it was that easy...

Answer (score 2):

You can make the line invisible this way:

```
shp.Line.Visible = MsoFalse
```